# Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, mediatr, mediator

i am getting mediatr error in a handler i have added dependency in `Startup.cs` still i am getting above error i have AddInfoRequestHandler which has following constructor arguments

```
public class AddInfoRequestHandler : IRequestHandler<AddInfoRequest, ResponseBase>
    {
        private Repository Repository { get; set; }
        private InfoUtility InfoUtility { get; set; }

        public AddInfoRequestHandler(Repository repository, InfoUtility infoUtility)
        {
            Repository = repository;
            InfoUtility = infoUtility;
        }


    public class InfoUtility
        {
            private IRepository Repository { get; set; }
            private string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    
            public InfoUtility(IRepository repository, string connectionString)
            {
                Repository = repository;
                ConnectionString = connectionString;
            }
```

In `Startup.cs` added following code

```
 services.For<IRequestHandler<AddInfoRequest, ResponseBase>>()
                .Use<AddInfoRequestHandler>()

 services.For<InfoUtility>()
                .Use<InfoUtility>()
                .Ctor<string>("ConnectionString")
                .Is(x => x.GetInstance<IConfiguration>().GetConnectionString("Info"));
```

can anybody tell me what is the issue here in adding dependency here

Comment: What is the exact error message ?

Comment: @J.Memisevic exact error msg is  'Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[AddInfoRequest,.ResponseBase]. Register your handlers with the container. See the samples

Comment: Are us using structure map for DI ?

Comment: Please add the complete error message of the exception and all its inner exceptions, including the full stack trace, to your question. And please turn your question into a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I think register

```
services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(typeof(AddInfoRequestHandler).Assembly));
```

for net 7.0

Comment: i am using .net core 3.1